# OpenGL ES 2.0 NVIDIA TEGRA 2 Unrolling

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I got a problem on one of my new shader.

When I try the shader on different devices, the shader compiles and runs smoothly.

When I try it on the NVIDIA TEGRA 2 GPU, running native code, I get the following compile error:

Shader failed to compile. Vertex Shader
(0) : error C6002: Instruction limit of 256 exceeded; 532 instructions needed to compile program
86 lines, 1 errors.

I think it is due to some sort of unroll the NVIDIA's gcg compiler performs but I cannot figure out how to solve this situation.

Now, I tried to reduce the type of the if/else statements just to not be if/else if but a chain of simple consecutive ifs (just to see if the problem was solved) but it didn't work.

I tried to remove all the if conditions by leaving just one and the shader compiles well (though it does not do what I actually need).

This is the code of my vertex shader, the fragment shader just contains the gl_color information and compiles well.

```
void main(){

//Converto direttamente in int, cosi le divisioni dopo sono piu veloci
int_character_position = int(character_position);   

uniform_reference =  (int_character_position / 4);

uniform_reference_sub_item = int(mod(character_position,4.0));  

if(uniform_reference == 0) {        
    working_float = charsequence_1[uniform_reference][uniform_reference_sub_item];      
} else if(uniform_reference == 1) {     
    working_float = charsequence_1[uniform_reference][uniform_reference_sub_item];              
} else if(uniform_reference == 2) {
    working_float = charsequence_1[uniform_reference][uniform_reference_sub_item];
} else if(uniform_reference == 3) {
    working_float = charsequence_1[uniform_reference][uniform_reference_sub_item];
} else if(uniform_reference == 4) {
    working_float = charsequence_2[uniform_reference - 4][uniform_reference_sub_item];
} else if(uniform_reference == 5) {
    working_float = charsequence_2[uniform_reference - 4][uniform_reference_sub_item];
} else if(uniform_reference == 6) {
    working_float = charsequence_2[uniform_reference - 4][uniform_reference_sub_item];
} else if(uniform_reference == 7) {
    working_float = charsequence_2[uniform_reference - 4][uniform_reference_sub_item];
} else if(uniform_reference == 8) {
    working_float = charsequence_3[uniform_reference - 8][uniform_reference_sub_item];
} else if(uniform_reference == 9) {
    working_float = charsequence_3[uniform_reference - 8][uniform_reference_sub_item];
} else if(uniform_reference == 10) {
    working_float = charsequence_3[uniform_reference - 8][uniform_reference_sub_item];
} else if(uniform_reference == 11) {
    working_float = charsequence_3[uniform_reference - 8][uniform_reference_sub_item];
} else if(uniform_reference == 12) {
    working_float = charsequence_4[uniform_reference -12][uniform_reference_sub_item];
} else if(uniform_reference == 13) {
    working_float = charsequence_4[uniform_reference -12][uniform_reference_sub_item];
} else if(uniform_reference == 14) {
    working_float = charsequence_4[uniform_reference -12][uniform_reference_sub_item];
} else if(uniform_reference == 15) {
    working_float = charsequence_4[uniform_reference -12][uniform_reference_sub_item];
} else if(uniform_reference == 16) {
    working_float = charsequence_5[uniform_reference -16][uniform_reference_sub_item];
} else if(uniform_reference == 17) {
    working_float = charsequence_5[uniform_reference -16][uniform_reference_sub_item];
} else if(uniform_reference == 18) {
    working_float = charsequence_5[uniform_reference -16][uniform_reference_sub_item];
} else if(uniform_reference == 19) {
    working_float = charsequence_5[uniform_reference -16][uniform_reference_sub_item];
} else if(uniform_reference == 20) {
    working_float = charsequence_6[uniform_reference -20][uniform_reference_sub_item];
} else if(uniform_reference == 21) {
    working_float = charsequence_6[uniform_reference -20][uniform_reference_sub_item];
} else if(uniform_reference == 22) {
    working_float = charsequence_6[uniform_reference -20][uniform_reference_sub_item];
} else if(uniform_reference == 23) {
    working_float = charsequence_6[uniform_reference -20][uniform_reference_sub_item];
}                   
v_texCoord.y = a_texture.y;
v_texCoord.x = a_texture.x + ( 0.0105 * float(working_float));
gl_Position = myMVPMatrix * myVertex;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenGL ES 2.0 implementations usually have a maximum number of instructions that they support, but a minimum number is not mandated by the API as it is impractical. The Nvidia Tegra implementation compiles the source to 532 instructions, which exceeds its maximum limit. The only possibility you have (apart from modifying the OpenGL ES 2.0 implementation) is to rewrite the shader so that it can be compiled to fewer instructions.

Without knowing the details of the Nvidia implementation, a statement like `working_float = charsequence_6[uniform_reference -20][uniform_reference_sub_item];`, combined with branching, does in the end result in multiple instructions (you have subtraction, loading, storing and array indexing there). Branching in general is often problematic as the compiler may not be able to compile multiple instructions to be run in parallel due to different code flows.

Your if - else if - else if code is pretty easy to rewrite so that it can be compiled to less instructions while still having the same meaning:

```
if(uniform_reference < 4) {        
    working_float = charsequence_1[uniform_reference][uniform_reference_sub_item];
} else if(uniform_reference < 8) {
    working_float = charsequence_2[uniform_reference - 4][uniform_reference_sub_item];
} else if(uniform_reference < 12) {
    working_float = charsequence_3[uniform_reference - 8][uniform_reference_sub_item];
} else if(uniform_reference < 16) {
    working_float = charsequence_4[uniform_reference -12][uniform_reference_sub_item];
} else if(uniform_reference < 20) {
    working_float = charsequence_5[uniform_reference -16][uniform_reference_sub_item];
} else if(uniform_reference < 24) {
    working_float = charsequence_6[uniform_reference -20][uniform_reference_sub_item];
}
```

That might already fit to the 256 instruction limit. (In the shader code, a thumb of rule is that often simply the size of the GLSL code roughly defines the number of instructions.) If not, it seems that you can replace `uniform_reference - {4,8,etc}` with `uniform_reference_sub_item` since it seems to be the same value anyway; this will save a few instructions as well. Ultimately, you can put the charsequence_[123456] values into an array and index it based on uniform_reference divided by a constant, as well as the charsequence instead, so that in the end you'd have something like this:

```
working_float = charsequence[uniform_reference / 4][uniform_reference - uniform_reference_sub_item][uniform_reference_sub_item];
```

Maybe you can also merge the two arrays indexed by `uniform_reference` and `uniform_reference_sub_item` to get rid of one level of indexing as well.

Comment: thank you very much. I have modified my if statements accordingly just after I have published my request and I was here to update the community on the problem's resolution. 

Your answer is anyway superb. Thank you very much for your kind assistance. The shader code was quite a prototype and in the end it was far more complicated than it was actually required to be :) 


Thanks a lot man.